# Returning different types from a property basing on some input

Tags: c#

I have a library i'm using that uses Licenses , and I would like to create a function that returns the right license based on the input.

This is a simplified verison of the class I'm using:

```
public class Settings {
  private Aspose.Words.License lic;
  private Aspose.Pdf.License plic; // new license

  public License License {
    get {
      if (this.lic == null) {
        this.lic = new License();
        this.lic.SetLicense("Aspose.Total.lic");
      }
      return this.lic;
    }
  }
}
```

so you can see, there are 2 License files present, 1 in the `Aspose.Words` namespace and one in the `Aspose.Pdf` namespace.

There are more licenses present, but in this example I'm using 2

So how would you modify the License attribute that it returns the right license.

my first go would be a switch case in a function and insert as string, but I don't know if you can request based on namespace values or so?

Comment: looks like some code is missing - `this.lic` - where is that field / property?

Comment: Watch out for Aspose.Pdf and embedding images in tables. Buggy as hell. **hangs** for some resolutions&scaling. [See support forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/626495/aspose.aspx).

Comment: @Alex srry, now it has the propper setup. So the pdf license can't be return in this example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked in Aspose.PDF v 9.6.0 and it seems that Aspose.Pdf.License is a standalone class, no base class, no interfaces.

If the same stands for your case, then there is no way. Since Aspose.Words.License and Aspose.Pdf.License are completely unrelated, there is no way of conditionally returning them fro the same property, **unless**:

- you change the property's type from License to plain object
- you rewrite all your license-related classes to be generic-over-licensetype

First solution has a drawback - you will need to cast the object back to the correct license type whenever you want to use it. Very irritating in use.

Second solution has a drawbacks - your code will get complicated and you may need to change many other pieces of code from `Settings` to `Settings<X>`.

```
public class Settings<TLic> where TLic : class, new(){ 
  private TLic wlic;

  public TLic License {
    get {
      if (this.lic == null) {
        dynamic temp = new TLic();
        temp.SetLicense("Aspose.Total.lic");
        this.lic = temp;
      }
      return this.lic;
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var sett1 = new Settings<Aspose.Words.License>();
var wordsLicense1 = sett1.License;

var sett2 = new Settings<Aspose.Pdf.License>();
var pdfLicense2 = sett2.License;
```

Edit:

OOorr.. you can rewrite the *property* into a *method* like Fabjan suggested. This will save you from updating all "Settings" references, but will force you to update all proeprty references and make them method calls..

Afterthought: If you are working on a common piece of code used in many projects, and **if each of your projects will be using only ONE license type**, then you can actually get away without updating refences by using some dirty inheritance tricks :)

```
public class SettingsBase<TLic> where TLic : class, new(){ 
  private TLic wlic;

  public TLic License {
    get {
      if (this.lic == null) {
        dynamic temp = new TLic();
        temp.SetLicense("Aspose.Total.lic");
        this.lic = temp;
      }
      return this.lic;
    }
  }
}
```

Usage in Project-1:

```
// in another file
public class Settings : SettingsBase<Aspose.Words.License> { }

// then
var sett = new Settings();
var wordsLicense = sett.License;
```

Usage in Project-2:

```
// in another file
public class Settings : SettingsBase<Aspose.Pdf.License> { }

// then
var sett = new Settings();
var pdfLicense = sett.License;
```

Comment: Wow nice! but can you do the loadoptions in the same class? And just so you know I'm using Cells, Email, Pdf, Slides and words of Aspose :)

Comment: @Kiwi: You can try to do it with `dynamic` trick. The above will work only because both of the classes contain the similar-looking `SetLicense(string)` method. If the options API is coherent, then it may work too. Sorry, I cannot check, I only see Pdf part, I don't have Words lib at hand.

Answer (score 2):

First of all i'd use using directive to make things simpler :

```
using WordsLicense = Aspose.Words.License;
using PdfLicence = Aspose.Pdf.License;
```

Then we can create a generic method that returns instance (it'd be more convenient to use generic properties but unfortunately they are still in the development at this time):

```
public class Settings {
   private WordsLicense wlic;
   private PdfLicence plic;

    public static T GetLicense<T>() where T : class
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(WordsLicense)) { if (wlic == null) wlic = new WordsLicense(); return wlic as T; }
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(PdfLicence)) { if (plic == null) plic = new PdfLicence(); return plic as T; }
        return null;
    }   
}
```

Comment: this still results in a load of if statements, akin to a switch statement. Code smell.

Comment: @Alex this classes has nothing in common. They do not have a common interface or something like this. How is it possible to determine the right type without use of `if`s or switch ? The only alternative is to return object or create 3 different properties one for each

Comment: @Alex: something, somewhere, **must** make the choice over the requested license type. Choice means either: if tree, switch/case, templates/generics, polymorphism. However, for templates/generics, something, somewhere must first create the an **instance of correct type**. This means that somewhere you have to either hardcode the instantiation, or you have to **choose** the correct type. See the recursion? If a **choice** comes from use case, you can't escape it.

Comment: Instead of if's you could use a dictionary/factory. A generic method which tests all possible cases of `T` is somehow unnessecarily generic, in my opinion.

Comment: @LInsoDeTeh: (sorry for a little off topic, but as I was replying to Alex..) that's true! dictionary or any other map would do the trick, but only because the license objects are small. Still, there'd be ifs/switches/loops inside (just hidden from our eyes), and also you have to explicitely fill (hardcode) the dictionary beforehand, so making the choice is not avoided.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I should have been a bit clearer. The dictionary / factory would be much less code-smelly. You *could* fill the dictionary with reflection in a static ctor, for example. A load of manual if statements invalidates open closed - what if another license is added? We need to modify our code, in order to add an if statement for this new license.

Comment: ...but as @quetzalcoatl mention in your answer, there's no base class or interface... so this could be a bit tricky.

Comment: @Alex still we need to modify the dictionary in this case ... Hard coding of this kind of things should be generally avoided but in this case i am not sure. Yes we can do mapping however it doesn't completely addresses the problem... We still need to use reflection (which violates open close principles even more not to mention that it is far from being optimal performance wise)  or to modify our dictionary

Comment: I don't agree it violates OC even more - we don't have to modify our **code** if a new License was added. As for performance - static ctor - happens once. Less of a concern. Either way, there's not really an optimal solution, because of the 3rd party library not inheriting the licenses from any base type of any kind!

Comment: @Alex you're correct. Other question is if it's Dictionary<string, TValue> what is this TValue should be ? We do not have any base type or interface here. :\ And that's the problem in my opinion